# Why $\frac{1}{z}$ is conformal at $0$

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

In Rudin Example 10.4 it is said that $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ is holomorphic at $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ (which i checked through Cauchy-Riemann equations).

What is going on at $0$? How can I establish conformity for $f$ at $0$? Is it just a convention?

Comment: $f(z)=\frac1z$ is not defined at $z=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is going on at $0$ is that it doesn't belong to the domain of $f$.

Comment: Should I change the question to emphasis, that I'm talking about Mobius transformation, or should I ask a new question?

Comment: Perhaps that asking a new question would be the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is not defined at $z=0$. Moreover, the singularity at $z=0$ is not [removable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity): there is no entire function $g$ extending $f$, in the sense that $g(z)=f(z)$ for $z\ne0$.

Contrast this with $h(z)=z^2/z$ or $h(z)=\sin(z)/z$, which are not defined at $z=0$ but can be extended to entire functions.